# Move dynamicly loaded image without ID

Tags: css

I want to change the position of a digital signature on an invoice, which gets generated every time someone signs online. The image does not have a tag however, and I cannot edit the HTML but only add custom CSS.

The structure looks like this:

```
<div id="products">
< texts, tables etc >
<img scr="https://signature.amazonsaws.com/uploads/123456"
</div>
```

I was thinking about some regex-like CSS scripts what looks for the amazonaws string, calls it and then moves this image to a different position. I am new to CSS, is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: `#products > img` will select all images that are direct children of `#products`. for better specificity you could use `#products > img:first-of-type` to select the first image that is a direct child of `#products`, or use the `nth`-selector if its not the first `img`-element that is a child of `#products`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute selector that checks value contains a specific text as following:

```
#products img[src*="amazonsaws"]
```

if you replace * with ^, it will check values starting with the text given

```
#products img[src^="https://signature.amazonsaws.com/"]
```